# How to handle httpClient respond right?

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-6.0

Because of Net 6.0 usage I'm frustrated how to convert old HttpWebResponse to httpClient

Could someone help me to handle it right?

I have httpClient request

```
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
    {
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | 
            DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    }
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod.Post, url));
```

And I have old HttpWebResponse

```
    using (var dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var reqDataByte = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetBytes(reqData);
        dataStream.Write(reqDataByte, 0, reqDataByte.Length);
    }

    using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        var responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        if (responseStream != null)
            using (var streamReader =
                new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding)))
            {
                 getString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
    }
```

Couldn't understand how to handle respond with httpClient right

```
    using var dataStream = httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    var reqDataByte = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetBytes(reqData);
    dataStream.CopyToAsync(reqDataByte, 0, reqDataByte.Length);

    using var response = (HttpWebResponse) httpClient.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    using var streamReader =
        new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding));
    getString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: One thing that stands out to me is that you are using an `async` method without using `await`, change this line `dataStream.CopyToAsync(reqDataByte, 0, reqDataByte.Length);` to `await dataStream.CopyToAsync(reqDataByte, 0, reqDataByte.Length);`.

Comment: Make sure the Status in the response is 200.  You may be getting an error dues to a 400 or 500 error status.  The latest requirements is that you use TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 for encryption.  SSL and TTLS 1.0 and 1.1 are obsolete.

Comment: You should also be awaiting this line `using var dataStream = httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);` should be `using var dataStream = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simply post raw bytes and get a string response back it is quite simple. You will need this to be an async method and await the async calls.

```
var reqDataByte = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetBytes(reqData);
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new ByteArrayContent(reqDataByte));
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    getString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else
{
    //Handle any unsuccessful post
}
```